# Countdown timer that stops and reset on 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, nstimer

Got an issue with my countdown timer who don't want to countdown from 60 and reset when 0 is reached. At the moment it just sets its label 0 and start counting down to -1, 2-... How do I get it to start from 60 on iOS in xcode?

**.m file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    int timeTick;
    NSTimer *timer;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)stopStartBtn:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];

    timeTick = 3;

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTicker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)myTicker{
    timeTick--;

    NSString *timeString =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    self.display.text = timeString;

    if(timer >= 0){
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    timeTick = 3;
}

@end
```

**.h File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
    - (IBAction)stopStartBtn:(id)sender;


    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently starts the timer at 0, decrements it, and then checks it it has reached 60. Obviously that won't happen.

If you want to start at 60 and stop at 0 then you need to set `timeTick` to `60` in `viewDidLoad` and check for a value of `0` in `myTicker`.

And don't forget to call `[super viewDidLoad];` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

You also need to fix your check to see if you've reached zero. Right now you are looking at the `timer` pointer instead of `timeTick` integer.

Change:

```
if(timer >= 0){
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

to:

```
if (timeTick <= 0) {
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

You are also never setting your `timer` instance variable. You actually set a local variable of the same name.

Change:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTicker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

to:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTicker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Ive tried it but it still does not stop att 0 and get a reset. I updated the code I use

Comment: That's because you are checking if `tick >= 0`. You want to check if `tick <= 0`.

Comment: That didn't make any difference. Its like the timer never enters the "if" statement

Comment: Still no luck with it. Do you know any other way to make a countdown with a reset at 0?

Comment: What actually happens when you run your app? Does the timer work at all?

Comment: Yes the timer is counting down but it does not stop at 0 it keeps counting down to -1, -2 etc.

Comment: Awesome that fixed the issue! Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface Ovning1 ()
{
   int timeTick;
   NSTimer *timer;
}
@end

@implementation Ovning1


- (IBAction)stopStartBtn:(id)sender {

    [timer invalidate];

    timeTick = 60;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTicker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)myTicker{

    timeTick--;

    NSString *timeString =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    self.display.text = timeString;


    if(timeTick <= 0){
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive tried it but it still does not stop att 0 and get a reset. I updated the code I use